# Apache2 + Python

Tags: python, apache

I'm trying to run a simple Python script on my Apache2 Web-Server. But I get following Error. Please help me, I don't get it. Thank you.

**File:**

```
print('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n')
print()
print("Hello, World!")
```

**Browser-Error**

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

**Error-Log**

```
[Fri May 13 13:35:05.520836 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 12967] [client ::1:41077] AH01215: (8)Exec format error: exec of '/var/www/html/index.py' failed
[Fri May 13 13:35:05.522775 2016] [cgi:error] [pid 12967] [client ::1:41077] End of script output before headers: index.py
```

Comment: This might help: http://serverfault.com/questions/107952/premature-end-of-script-and-exec-format-error

Comment: Can you run the script by hand, and is apache using python 3 to run it?

Comment: Running python as CGI is so 1990s. But if you really want to go this route, note that there has to be a blank line ('\n') after the headers.

Answer (score 0):

I can easily execute the file via python index.py in the terminal and it looks like that:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

()
Hello, World!
```

It seems like i`m using python 2.7. (python -v). "note that there has to be a blank line ('\n') after the headers" What do you mean with that? Could you give me an Code example please?

Answer (score 0):

In python 2.7, **print** itself is a function , no need to use **print()**, change your code to:

```
print "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n"
print ""
print "Hello, World!"
```

This should work.

Comment: Can you please check if your script has execute permission, by doing a ls -ld </path/to/script> and also is the error-log showing same error after changing to the above code?

Comment: I'm not sure about the www-data because i execute with pi user. -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi      www-data   81 Mai 13 17:34 index.py The error-log is still the same.

Comment: The ownership of the file should be www-data, as apache runs as that user. Can you please do `chown www-data </path/to/script>` and then Could you restart apache and try as it might be serving the old cached file.